# Disable letter key+SPACE for diacritics in Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, typing

I've been accidentally getting diacritics (accents, etc) on my letters as I type, and I've realized what's happened is that in Windows, if you press SPACE while a letter key is down, you get a menu with modified versions of that letter. This is causing me to make typing errors. Is there any way to disable this behavior?

I'm on Windows 11, btw.

Comment: I do not see that here:  Windows 11 Pro, Office 365, English setup and no other languages.

Comment: Please add more details, such as your language and keyboard layout.

Comment: @harrymc I was just about to, but then I figured out the problem was not in my settings at all. https://superuser.com/a/1753523/75425

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. I installed Power Toys, and it comes with a widget called Quick Accent, which does exactly this. Thanks to everyone for helping explore this, and sorry if anyone was down a rabbit hole.

Hopefully this answer will be findable for anyone else who accidentally does this.

[image: Power Toys Quick Accent settings]

Comment: This was it! I wish these wouldn't be enabled by default when PowerToys updates, because I don't remember this feature the first time I installed it. I think it's a great tool, but it gets in the way when I'm gaming or coding =|